# how to find an array with a particular value and map to another array in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have an array this.data that has an array of platforms and
platforms has an array of  sectionlist
( sectionList is an array of few values like sectionName , sectionid, sectionVal etc. )

I need to map a new array value (this.newSectionList) to the old sectionList for a specific sectionid.

I can map each value within the the sectionList like this

```
this.data.platforms.find(a => a.platformId === platformId).sectionList.find(f => f.sectionid === this.sectionid).sectionName = this.newSectionList.sectionName;

this.data.platforms.find(a => a.platformId === platformId).sectionList.find(f => f.sectionid === this.sectionid).sectionVal = this.newSectionList.sectionVal;
```

Instead i want to map the entire sectionList to this.newSectionList . What is the easiest way?
This syntax below is wrong but how do i achieve this?

```
this.data.platforms.find(a => a.platformId === platformId).sectionList.find(f => f.sectionid === this.sectionid) = this.newSectionList;
```

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: i edited my question- actually i have a data coming from the first api and another data coming from second api. i need to update the data from the first api with the second api just for a particular array with a matching value .

Comment: Are u looking to copy only matching keys from one object to the other

Comment: If you would have just provided sample input data and expected output data, this question would have been answered hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer step by step. The "key" is use the [spread operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#spread) to give all the properties to the section

```
const platform=this.data.platforms.find(a => a.platformId === platformId)
const section=platform?
        platform.sectionList.find(f => f.sectionid ===this.sectionid):null

if (section)
   section={...newSection}
else
   platform.sectionList.push(newSection)
```